# Activity not reading serialized objects from another activity

Tags: android, serialization, arraylist

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is save an ArrayList of Strings in one activity and then read them in another. The file is created (I can see it in the DDMS) but for some reason I can't get the activity to read the objects.

Here's the reading code:

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("purchased_songs.obj");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    purchasedSongs = (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    for(int i=0;i<purchasedSongs.size();i++)
    Log.d("purchased songs",purchasedSongs.get(i));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here's the writing code:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("purchased_songs.obj",MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    os.writeObject(purchasedSongs);
    os.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is bad idea, what you are doing. Put your stuff in Bundle and pass the bundle.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I'm relatively new to Android programming but I need this information to be saved if the user closes the app and then have it ready when the user starts it again at a later time. Could I do that with a bundle?

Comment: Have you considered storing data with SQLite? You can read about that here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: @Karakuri I've thought about it but figured this was a lot easier. I'm just saving an ArrayList of Strings of songs that the user purchased so that the UI can update itself and tell them what they did and didn't purchase.

Comment: You can do all of that with SQLite and a proper ContentProvider. Android has some APIs that also facilitate loading the information off the UI thread and getting new data (also in the background) when your SQLite data changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I figured out what is wrong.

Change

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("purchased_songs.obj");
```

to

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("purchased_songs.obj");
```